# Packaging SharePoint 2013 List, Site, and Reusable Workflow and How to Deploy the Package

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

How to deploy a List workflow (not reusable) which is created in SharePoint designer 2013 to another site collection without recreating it again? I have got [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/30/packaging-list-site-and-reusable-workflow-and-how-to-deploy-the-package.aspx) link which is a good post about this issue. I have tried whatever is mentioned in the post. The workflows get deployed  successfully and can also be seen in SharePoint designer 2013, but when I click on it gives an error. Anyone any ideas about it?
[image]

Comment: Do you have workflow foundation installed in your environment?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx